# Identifying an office plant

Tags: identification, office-gardening

Is anyone able to identify this small office plant?

It seems to get only a small amount of natural light, if that helps.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Syngonium of some variety - I can't decide whether, although it looks  healthy, it's stunted because it doesn't have enough root room, or whether it's simply a dwarf variety of some kind. These plants do best in low to medium light without direct sunlight; variegation of the leaves is often improved in brighter light for some varieties. Some information and images of various  types of Syngonium here https://agreenhand.com/syngonium-varieties-for-growing-indoors/